# How to load an the next element upon a button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I show the next p after the last p that has a `display:block`

```
<p id="test1">test1</p>
<p id="test2">test2</p>

<p id="test3">test3</p>

<button onclick="">show next p</button>
```

noting that in CSS by default:

```
#test1 {display:block;}
#test2, #test3 {display:none;}
```

Comment: Using jQuery or not?

Comment: doesn't really matter whatever u want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`processParas` accepts a collection of hidden paras and returns [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) that is called each time the button is clicked. This function reveals each consecutive hidden para in the collection until the index (initially set to zero) hits the length of `paras`.

You don't really need a `display: block` on paras as they default to that style, so here I'm simply removing a class ("hidden") instead.

```js
// Select all the hidden paras, and the button
const paras = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// Assign the function returned by processParas as the function
// called by the click event listener
button.addEventListener('click', processParas(paras), false);

// processParas accepts a collection of paras
function processParas(paras) {

  // It sets index to 0 _before_ the closure is returned
  let index = 0;

  // A closure is a function that has access to the
  // variables in its outer lexical enviroment even when
  // it's returned. We need to assign a function to the event listener
  // and we need to set index to zero, but we can't set index to zero in
  // the returned function because it would be zero everytime the button
  // is clicked. Using a closure ensures we can initialise index, and still
  // return a function that operates normally
  return function () {

    // If the button is clicked we check that the index is less
    // that the collection length
    if (index < paras.length) {

      // If it is we simply remove the hidden class to make
      // the para visible
      paras[index].classList.remove('hidden');

      // Then we increase index for the next check
      ++index;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<p>test1</p>
<p class="hidden">test2</p>
<p class="hidden">test3</p>
<p>test4</p>
<p class="hidden">test5</p>

<button>show next para</button>
```

Comment: thank you still a bit confused but it worked in the end

Comment: @MiladDeraawi, I've added a link to MDNs docs on closures, and some further notes in the code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with jquery like below;

```
      $("#test4").css({
        'display' : 'block',
      });
```

```js
function next(){
   $("#test4").css({
      'display' : 'block',
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'>
<p id="test1">test1</p>
<p id="test2">test2</p>
<p id="test3">test3</p>
<p id="test4" style='display:none'>test4</p>
</div>


<button onclick="next()">show next p</button>
```